# Popup window with error when right-clicking in the Tridion GUI

Tags: tridion

When I try to right-click on items in the Tridion content manager I get an error.
The error is inside Tridion's own error display mechanism, showing the IP address.

Here's a screen grab:

[image: Error message "Object does not support this property or method"]

It's worth noting that this is inside a Windows XP Mode VM, across a VPN to an IP address on a client network.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make sure that your browser security settings are set up correctly in Internet Explorer:

From the Internet Explorer menu bar, select Tools > Internet Options.

On the Security tab, select the Internet content zone.

Click the Custom Level button and enable the following settings :

ActiveX controls and plug-ins:

- Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins
- Script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting

Downloads:

- File download

Miscellaneous:

- Submit non encrypted form data

Scripting:

- Active scripting
- Allow paste operations via script (Internet Explorer 6.0 SP2)
- Allow Programmatic clipboard access (Internet Explorer 7.0 and 8.0)

Click OK to enable these settings.

On the Security tab, select the Trusted Sites Web content zone.

Click the Sites button. In the Trusted sites dialog that appears, type the name of the Content Manager Web address, then click Add. Click Close to close the Trusted sites dialog. This setting ensures that you can access all content within a Component.

Select the Privacy tab and click the Advanced button. Select the Override automatic cookie handling option. Select the Always Allow Session Cookies option. Click OK.

Click OK in the Internet Options window.

Comment: It's actually not what documentation suggest. By doing this you will compromise your security settings for the internet. What you should do is just add you CME to trusted sites of Local Intranet. This way you will not compromise your global security. Besides Local Intranet has lower security then Internet and you will not need to do any other modifications

Comment: I have to agree with user978511 (boy that's awkward to say :) Add it to your Intranet zone instead and then verify that it has all of the required settings.

Answer (score 5):

Browser configuration settings are available in [online documenation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?action=html&resource=login.html&destination=/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011&lang=en-US#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql;jsessionid=124ke8dtvh9ur?id=124ke8dtvh9ur&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011&lang=en-US&action=search&query=events&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1309417963999&eventType=lcContent.loadDocet_concept_382BF5DCD4BF401ABDE0B58D28E1B11C&query=events&scope=&resource=08e288f2-faef-470d-b26e-7f98d85e9595.xml&filename=EventTriggers.xml&docid=et_concept_382BF5DCD4BF401ABDE0B58D28E1B11C&inner_id=&tid=29213774-9889-4628-b74a-2e8c645ea8fb&addHistory=true), I suggest adding as a "Trusted Site"

Comment: As noted in user978511's comment to another answer, Local Intranet is what should be used, as specified in the documentation.